# Using Apache mod_rewrite for conditional redirection if URL exists

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm migrating a large site (with significant changes to each page), and want a test group of users to be automatically redirected from the current site to the new site as each page is completed.

What was

```
www.mysite.com/admin/somefile.php
```

will become

```
admin.mysite.com/somefile.php
```

As each page is migrated to the new site, I want users from a specific IP address to be automatically redirected to it. This looks like a case for the '-U' (existing URL) flag of RewriteCond. The mod_rewrite statements (for www.mysite.com) would be something along the lines of

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 123\.123\.123\.123           # for test users only
  RewriteCond http://admin.mysite.com/$1 -U               # if new page exists
  RewriteRule /admin/(.*) http://admin.mysite.com/$1 [R=302,L]  # then redirect
```

However, this doesn't seem to work - perhaps because the $1 parameter is being referenced before being defined?

Can anyone advise how this can be achieved?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: Yes, you CAN reference $1 there -- it will be known when RewriteCond gets evaluated (RewriteRule's pattern is evaluated first). I'm just unsure if `-U` works this way (if admin.mysite declared as separate site). In any case -- I recommend enabling rewrite debug (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log for exact details.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, LazyOne – you gave me confidence to pursue it (if you make it an answer I'll accept it).

I think the problem was simply in using /admin instead of ^admin; my final mod_rewrite statements are:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 123\.123\.123\.123           # for test users only
  RewriteCond http://admin.mysite.com/$1 -U               # if new page exists
  RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) http://admin.mysite.com/$1 [R=302,L]  # then redirect
```

...which seems to correctly serve the page from the new site if it exists, otherwise serves the page from the old site.

Answer (score -1):

You could use it this way to manipulate `URI`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://admin.mysite.com/#1 [R=302,L]
```

Hope this works. BTW, you can test your rewrite online here http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: Surely this will attempt to redirect to the new site whether or not the page has been converted to the new site? This wouldn't fulfil my needs. Thanks anyway.